# better way to improve my code without many for loops

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to optimize my code. I have an array of JSON objects and I need to loop through the objects and see if they contain several words and keep track of the JSON objects if the contain all the worlds, not just one but all of them. I don't want to pass to the function an array of worlds because I feel I will have to add another for loop.Right now, my code goes through every input field and if it's not empty call the function and pass the world in the input field. My code works fine if I just check one word, but I need to check more than one and keep track of the objects that contain all the worlds

My code:
 workOrdersArray it's a global array.

```
function searchWO (workOrdersArray) {
            var filteredWO = [];

            for (var i=0; i < workOrdersArray.length; i++) {
                for (var prop in workOrdersArray[i]) {
                    if (myArray[i][prop] == nameKey) {
                            filteredWO.push(workOrdersArray[i]);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Example:
If one input field has the world "Hello" and another input field says "Bye"

```
var array = [
    { "x":"Bye","y":"Bye","z":"Hello"},
    { "x":"Bye","y":"Bye","z":"Hi"},
    { "x":"Bye","y":"Hello","z":"Hi"},
];
```

I will store the JSON object inside of the array in an separate array. So the new array will have the obj1 and obj3

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show an example of how you call your function and what the desired result would be? It's not clear what `nameKey`, `myArray`, and `workOrdersArray` are. I've removed the "json" tag from your question, because [there's no such thing as a "json object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/): you're dealing with objects. Except the array that you've shown is not valid JS syntax, so please fix that too.

Comment: Given that, from your description, your code is working correctly and has no bugs, I think this question might be better suited for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Try flagging this question, ask for moderator intervention and request that the question be moved there. Note that this is just my opinion... the moderator may disagree (but there's no harm in asking).

Comment: @nnnnnn I have edited post

Comment: Your `array` is still not valid JS syntax. Did you intend to use `{}` rather than `[]`? Your function now makes even less sense, because now the body tries to use arguments that you've removed, and I think your desired behaviour would involve having the function accept more than one word as input. I meant for you to show some possible input, and also show the desired output if you call the function with that input, e.g., do you want to call it with something like `searchWO(['Hello', 'bye'])`, or `searchWO('Hello', 'bye')`, or...?

Comment: @nnnnnn something like this searchWO(['Hello', 'bye']).  Passing the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your array is a valid JavaScript array, but if your array is of the form like

```
var array = [
    { "x":"Bye","y":"Bye","z":"Hello"},
    { "x":"Bye","y":"Bye","z":"Hi"},
    { "x":"Bye","y":"Hello","z":"Hi"},
];
```

Then you may try this in ES6+:

```js
var array =  [
  { "x":"Bye","y":"Bye","z":"Hello"},
  { "x":"Bye","y":"Bye","z":"Hi"},
  { "x":"Bye","y":"Hello","z":"Hi"},
];

var keyName = ["Hello", "Bye"];

function searchWO (nameKey, myArray) {
  for(var key of nameKey){
     myArray = myArray.filter(obj => JSON.stringify(obj).indexOf('"' + key + '"') != -1);
  }
  return myArray;
}

// Loop Haters Gonna Hate
function searchWO2 (nameKey, myArray) {
    return nameKey.reduce((ans, key) => ans.filter(obj => JSON.stringify(obj).indexOf('"' + key + '"') != -1) , myArray);
}

console.log(searchWO(keyName, array.slice()));
console.log(searchWO2(keyName, array.slice()));
```

The `.slice()` is just a shallow copy as I don't want to modify the source array, you may omit it if you want.

Both function does the same job, choose one you like :)

**EDITED:**

To ensure the `indexOf` is searching the value instead of key, one can change to search

`'"' + key + '",'` and `'"' + key + '"}'`

Comment: if you stringify the object, then you might get a false positive if it has a **key** of *Hello* instead of a **value** of *Hello*

Comment: @shole. Sorry I forgot to put make it a valid array I was just writing a sudo one. does ES6+ works with any broweser? sorry I'm new into coding

Comment: @JoeLissner is there anyway to achive what I need without the stringify?

Comment: @JoeLissner You are right, how about change a bit to find "Hello",  and "Hello"} ?

Comment: @TamoDevelopers Modern browsers mostly support ES6+, you can see the details from here: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/  (IE11 is not counted as modern browser, oops)

Comment: @shole lol. Thanks a lot for you help I'm going to test it out

Comment: @TamoDevelopers Welcome, I am not that experienced in JS too, but I think this method's pitfall is that it depends on the implementation of `stringify`, like it *assumes* `stringify` will use double quote on the keys / values, trim the spaces, etc.

Comment: @shole wow you are a master!! It even works searching in the array that has objects inside of objects. just wow. What does the => do? eclipse marks it as a syntax error but the code runs like a champ

Comment: @TamoDevelopers  If you have nested objects, I must emphasize that the `.slice()` only do a shallow copy, not a deep one (though it is out of OP's scope).  `=>` is named arrow function, it's a ES6 syntax which is just a short form one-liner of traditional callback functions. You will instantly get it if you search "Arrow Functions in JavaScript" in Google :)

Comment: @TamoDevelopers Also a friendly reminder: Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem :) See also How does accepting an answer work?

Comment: @shole I coudn't mark the correct answer because I don't have 15 points yet

Comment: Dont worry, it's a general friendly tips for u only :)  Good Question